Axios CORS Error while trying to access data from endpoint using React Query?
in my NextJS app my React Query POST request below is trying to access data,
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import axios from 'axios'
import { DCMSRequestData, DCMSResponse } from '@/types/DCMSdata'

export default function useDCMSdata() {
  return useMutation<DCMSResponse, Error, DCMSRequestData>({
    mutationFn: async (requestData: DCMSRequestData) => {
      return axios
        .post(
          'https://supply-chain-wms-api-public-develop-internal-eks.eu-west-1.dev.hbi.systems/api/v1/order/query',
          requestData,
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'x-hbi-app-name': 'local-testing',
              Connection: 'keep-alive',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          },
        )
        .then((response) => response.data)
    },
  })
}

Here I am trying to call the mutate function within a useEffect,
useEffect(() => {
    const requestData: DCMSRequestData = {
      warehouse_ids: ['TestTransfer'],
      // statuses: ['string'],
      // orderTypes: ['string'],
      // transferIds: [0],
      page_size: 100,
      page: 1,
    }

    mutate(requestData, {
      onSuccess: (responseData) => {
        const fetchedOrders = responseData.data.data.map((order) => ({
          id: order.id,
          warehouseId: order.warehouse_id,
          status: order.status,
          transferId: order.transfer_id,
          selected: selectedIds.includes(order.id),
        }))
        setRows(fetchedOrders)
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
      },
    })
  }, [mutate, selectedIds])

Im thinking my syntax is wrong somewhere, I've taken a look at Tanstack docs but haven't been able to locate this problem.
Here is my error


CORS(Cross-Origin Resouce Sharing) error is a frontend issue because they occur in the browser when a client (the frontend) tries to access resources from a different origin. But the issue itself is server-side because it's teh server that needs to send the correct CORS headers in its response to tell the browser it is ok to make the request.
You are trying to get data from a third-party server. In this case, the third-party server blocks your website domain by default due to its CORS policy, which is why you are getting CORS error.
To get data without CORS errors, the third-party server should allow your website domain to make requests to the server. But it's not always possible if you can't control the third-party server. In this case, you have a few options:

User a proxy server: You can set up a backend server on your own domain that forwards requests to the third-party server.
You can use some browser extensions such as CORS Unblock, Allow CORS and etc.

